# Stack Every "Nth" Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to stack the data of every 5th column on top of each other leaving out rows with blanks.

I found an example that was using the same kinda logic, but it seems to cut off some off the bottom of each set:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!A$2,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-1),0)*5)`

Data:

|  | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Home | Cats | Dogs | Mice |  | Home | Cats | Dogs | Mice |  | Home | Cats | Dogs | Mice |
| **2** | Home 1-1 | 6 | 3 | 1 |  | Home 2-1 | 2 | 9 | 1 |  | Home 3-1 | 6 | 32 | 3 |
| **3** | Home 1-2 | 1 | 6 | 5 |  | Home 2-2 | 1 | 6 | 2 |  | Home 3-2 | 9 | 2 | 6 |
| **4** | Home 1-3 | 7 | 2 | 4 |  | Home 2-3 | 4 | 4 | 4 |  | Home 3-3 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| **5** | Home 1-4 | 9 | 4 | 5 |  | Home 2-4 | 8 | 4 | 6 |  | Home 3-4 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| **6** | Home 1-5 | 1 | 6 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | Home 3-5 | 3 | 8 | 4 |
| **7** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Home 3-6 | 2 | 9 | 1 |
| **8** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Home 3-7 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| **9** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Home 3-8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: What other post? What have you tried? Please edit your question to add this very relevant information.

Comment: Filter function?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft 365:
`=SORT(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(DROP(F:S,1),1),4))`

[image]

or:

`=LET(x,LAMBDA(data,LET(y,DROP(data,1),FILTER(y,INDEX(y,,1)<>""))),VSTACK(x(F:I),x(K:N),x(P:S)))`

If you're using an older Excel use something like:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)>4,"",
                 IF(ROW(A1)<=(MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)-1),
                    INDEX(F$2:INDEX(F:F,MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)),ROW(A1)),
                    IF(ROW(A1)<=(MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)+MATCH(9^9,$N:$N,1)-2),
                       INDEX(K$2:INDEX(K:K,MATCH(9^9,$N:$N,1)),ROW(A1)-MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)+1),
                       IF(ROW(A1)<=(MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)+MATCH(9^9,$N:$N,1)+MATCH(9^9,$S:$S,1)-3),
                       INDEX(P$2:INDEX(P:P,MATCH(9^9,$S:$S,1)),ROW(A1)-MATCH(9^9,$I:$I,1)-MATCH(9^9,$N:$N,1)+2),
                 ""))))
```

But it would be better to use helpers in that case.